# Constructive proof that the Lie functor is faithful?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, topos-theory, synthetic-differential-geometry

I am wondering how to show that the Lie functor taking Lie groups to Lie algebras is faithful? In particular, I am looking for a constructive proof, since I am working in the context of synthetic differential geometry (and thus restricted to intuitionistic logic).

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but my algebra background isn't that strong, and I mostly taught myself what little Lie theory I know.

Comment: This is false unless you restrict to connected Lie groups. I am not sure what's constructive, but what proofs have you seen? There's two that I know: one that first passes through formal group laws (in Serre's book on Lie groups) and one that passes through foliations (you can find this in Lee's book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reference with a proof given [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie's+three+theorems). It says "the second Lie theorem establishes that this functor is fully faithful". See also [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~vsv/liegroups2007/9.pdf).

For non-connected Lie groups the Lie functor is not faithful, see page $35$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&ved=0ahUKEwixnMP6upLKAhVCUBoKHdvZCsM4ChAWCFUwBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdiposit.ub.edu%2Fdspace%2Fbitstream%2F2445%2F63069%2F2%2Fmemoria.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH3kFbbtI46B_dTI08rEJ0n9DwfaA&sig2=sSSyzTAXZpO56TEk0gm4OQ&bvm=bv.110151844,d.d2s) for "explicit counterexamples".

Comment: "Faithful" is not synonymous with "injective on objects"... In fact these two properties are quite unrelated. Did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Sorry, this was not correct. I included the nLab reference now.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I had thought that the Lie functor was faithful for the entire category of Lie groups. Do you happen to know of an explicit counterexample by the way (i.e. a pair of distinct Lie group homomorphisms which map to the same Lie algebra homomorphism under the Lie functor?)

Comment: Yes, there are many explicit counterexamples. Just consider any two non-connected Lie groups $G$ and $H$ such that their respective identity connected components $G_I$ and $H_I$ are Lie groups themselves - see my edit.

Comment: To be rather silly: $G = \Bbb Z/2$, $H = *$.